# antd-form-redux how to submit form

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

I've installed [antd-form-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-form-redux), but when i try [import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfztu.png) it in my file i see warning "Module is not installed". I am able to create form, but i cannot handle submit. I did like in the example on github, but it does not work for me :< I am beginner in redux/react so maybe i made some mistake

```
...
render() {
   return(  
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
            ...
      </Form>);
}


export default reduxForm({
   form: 'ProductNewForm',
   onSubmit: (values, dispatch, props) => {
       console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
   }
})(connect(null, {createProduct})(ProductCreate));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the official antd Form that is imported from the antd package. Check this out, they provide a lot of good examples:

[AntD Form](https://ant.design/components/form/)

Also it would be great for you to find a good example of simple react-redux app to understand actions/reducers/props/store business.